Okta initiated logon to Azure B2C
We are trying to use Okta for external users to log in to our Azure B2C for API access. We have it working (ish) but it requires multiple clicks by the users and could end up being a bit confusing. What we get currently is:
User logs into Okta and clicks tile to B2C.
B2C sign in page appears and user has to click Azure Active Directory B2C button (there's also email and password boxes on the page)
This brings up another page that prompts of Sign in or Okta External button at the bottom.
Clicking the Okta External button gets you in.
We just want to go from Okta tile to the main page. AZ support says this is the way it is designed. Anyone have an idea if this is the correct behavior? This kind of setup is not going to fly.
We've gone through the integration provided by Okta and all is correct.

This sounds like SP Initiated?
Did you set "IdpInitiatedProfileEnabled" to "true" as per here.
And start off with something like this?
https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/generic/login?EntityId=<app-identifier-uri>&RelayState=<relay-state>

Update
Remembered that "We don't currently support scenarios where the initiating identity provider is an external identity provider federated with Azure AD B2C, such as Active Directory Federation Services or Salesforce. IdP-initiated flow is supported only for local account authentication in Azure AD B2C."
So the app -> Okta - click B2C federation button on Okta screen (B2C is an external IDP) -> authenticate on B2C logon screen (login / password) -> JWT returned to app
You should not see "Okta External button at the bottom" of the B2C logon screen.
It sounds like you have also configured Okta as a B2C external IDP which is wrong.

I'll check that out. Thanks.
